# php SELECT * FROM вывод id-2

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, select

Помогите пожалуйста как вывести по id так что когда число id росла выводился id-2 пост чтоб получилось SELECT * FROM chess WHERE id=$id-2

```
<div class="postblock">
     <?php
     $articles = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM chess WHERE id < 5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
     ?>
     <?php
     WHILE( $art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles) ){
         ?>
         <div class="post">
             <a href="http://localhost/madbet/posts"><img src="http://localhost/madbet/img/images/chess/<?php echo $art['image-1'] ?>"></a>
             <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo date_create($art['pubdate'])->Format('H:i');?></p>
             <a href="http://localhost/madbet/posts"><h1><?php echo mb_substr($art['title'],0,33)?></h1></a>
             <h4 style="margin-bottom:40px;"><?php echo mb_substr($art['text-1'],0,140).'...';?></h4>
         </div>
         <?php
     }
     ?>

 </div>
```

Comment: Непонятно. Покажите пример (данные и желаемый результат), что ли...

Comment: `id=id-2` <- это точно неземная математика!

Comment: `SELECT c1.* FROM chess c1 inner join chess c2 on c1.id = c2.id - 2`

Comment: А если id будет равен 2 или 1?

Comment: ну тогда нечего не должень выводит ! вот если у меня последний id 15 я хочу выводит все кроме 14,15

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно просто проигнорировать первые 2 записи, то

```
SELECT * FROM `chess` LIMIT 10000, 2
```

Если вам нужно проигнорировать запись по переданному номеру, а также на один меньше, то:

```
SELECT * FROM `chess` WHERE id != $id AND id != $id - 1
```

Comment: спасибо  большое